# How to convert json to string in golang and echo framework?

Tags: json, go, go-echo

I have a json that I receive by post

```
{"endpoint": "assistance"}
```

I receive this like this

```
json_map: = make (map[string]interface{})
```

Now I need to assign it to a variable as a string but I don't know how to do it.

```
endpoint: = c.String (json_map ["endpoint"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not to convert a JSON to a string but an empty interface `interface{}` to a `string` You can achieve this by doing a [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15):

```
endpoint, ok := json_map["endpoint"].(string)
if !ok {
  // handle the error if the underlying type was not a string
}
```

Also as **@Lex** mentionned, it would probably be much safer to have a Go struct defining your JSON data. This way all your fields will be typed and you will no longer need this kind of type assertion.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions details

Answer (score 2):

A type safe way to do this would be creating a struct that represents your request object and unmarshalling it.

This gives you a panic on unexpected requests.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type response struct {
    Endpoint string
}

func main() {
    jsonBody := []byte(`{"endpoint": "assistance"}`)
    data := response{}
    
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBody, &data); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(data.Endpoint)
}
// assistance
```

This program as an example safely decodes the JSON into a struct and prints the value.